# Como puedo generar el database Context por comando?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla en .net core y entity framework core, quiero separar el proyecto por capas para trabajar mas organizado, 
mis preguntas son las siguientes

1) A la solución tengo que agregar una librería de clase .net core ?
o una librería de clase estandar .net ?

2) Como puedo generar el archivo dbcontext usando scaffold por comandos en mi nueva capa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos te recomiendo que utilices .NET Standard ya que te va a generar un libreria compatible con las mayorias de implementaciones de .net (.NET Framework, dotnet core y xamarin).

Aqui te explican mas detalles:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Encuanto a la generacion de tu dbcontext usando scaffold

Si usas Visual Studio puedes seguir estas intrucciones para hacerlo con [NuGet Package Manager Console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console)

1.Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

2.Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Luego usas este comando para generar tu base de datos

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Sqlsever;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Docuementacion de Microsoft [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

Si usas Visual Studio Code seria usando dotnet CLI

tu proyecto deberia de lucir de esta forma

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Para instalar estos paquetes debes usar dotnet add package.

Luego de tener el proyecto de esta forma sin ningún error usas este comando:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=Server;Database=Dbname;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  --startup-project ..\ProyectoNETCore  -o Models
```

Recuerda que es importante especificar el **proyecto de inicio** que debe de ser un proyecto .net core de otra tendrías que agregarle el framework .net core al proyecto .netstandard, por que para que esto funcione debe de haber un proyecto usando .net core en algun lugar

Documentación oficial [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

[Enlace relacionado](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database)

Comment: Gracias ! me leer los links que me dejaste

Comment: Siempre a su orden